# Find the value of $C_3$ such that this sequence is null

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Consider the following sequence:

$$C_1n \exp\{-C_2 \ln (n)^{2C_3}\}, \,\,\,\,\, n\geq 1,$$

where $C_1,C_2>0$ are fixed constants. The exercise asks to find a value $C_3>0$ such that this sequence is null.

My reasoning is that $2C_3\ln (n)\leq\ln (n)^{2C_3}$ for $n$ large whenever $2C_3-1>0$ or $C_3>1/2$. Therefore it suffices to consider the sequence

$$C_1n \exp\{-2C_2C_3 \ln (n)\}=C_1n^{1-2C_2C_3}$$

which is null whenever $1-2C_2C_3<0$ or $C_3>1/(2C_2)$. Therefore any value of $C_3$ larger than $\max\{1/2,1/(2C_2\}$ will work.

Is this reasoning correct? Any feedback is very appreciated.

Comment: I think the reasoning is correct, yes. It's probably not the sharpest result, but if you're only asked for something that works, then it's good enough.

Comment: @user3733558 Thank you for your feedback. Do you see how to obtain a sharper value?

Comment: I don't. I based my statement on back-of-the-envelope calculations (finding the root of the derivative and a few numerical tests), and they suggest that $C_3>1/2$ is in fact a sufficient condition regardless of what $C_2$ is, but I don't have a rigorous proof.